# Read Lua table and put into JSON object using C++

Tags: c++, json, lua

I'm having a hard time while trying to integrate a Lua scripted system with a JSON library for outputting.

I want to get whatever the Lua function I'm calling returns and convert it to JSON (I'm trying to use [this lib](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)), but this task is proving utterly hard.

That's my farthest try so far:

```
void parseTable(lua_State* L, json& result)
{
    lua_pushnil(L);
    while (lua_next(L, -2) != 0) {
        auto key = lua_tostring(L, -2);
        auto value = parseLuaValue(L);

        result[key] = value;
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
}

json parseLuaValue(lua_State* L)
{
    json result;

    auto type = lua_type(L, -1);
    if (type == LUA_TBOOLEAN) {
        result = lua_toboolean(L, -1) != 0;
    } else if (type == LUA_TNUMBER) {
        result = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
    } else if (type == LUA_TSTRING) {
        result = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    } else if (type == LUA_TTABLE) {
        parseTable(L, result);
    };
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    return result;
}

json JSONScriptInterface::callFunction(int params)
{
    json result;
    int size = lua_gettop(m_luaState);
    if (protectedCall(m_luaState, params, 1) != 0) {
        LuaScriptInterface::reportError(nullptr, LuaScriptInterface::getString(m_luaState, -1));
    } else {
        result = parseLuaValue(m_luaState);
    }

    (...)
}
```

The Lua script running is:

```
function onRequest()
    return {
        ["bool"] = true,
        ["number"] = 50.0,
        ["string"] = "test",
    }
end
```

This is crashing at `while (lua_next(L, -2) != 0) {`, and I can't figure out why. It *always* happens when trying to get the second table value, in that case `["number"] = 50.0`. The first one works, so I think I'm manipulating the stack somewhat wrong.

I'm trying to learn the right way with [this](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2004-06/msg00325.html), but it's hard to understand. The process aborts with the following message:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (invalid key to 'next')
terminate called without an active exception
Signal: SIGABRT (Aborted)
```

So I guess that message is wrong somehow. Easy to guess, it's 11 years old, and Lua API must have changed a lot since then. What am I doing wrong to get that abort signal when trying to access the next table value, and why does it happen only on the second key?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
    lua_pop(L, 1);
```

in `parseLuaValue`.

Comment: I don't think it is. I almost verbatim copied from the reference, just changed printf to cout: [my impl](https://gist.github.com/ranisalt/14194febc9e69f2bc648), [manual impl](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_next) and it still bails out at the second iteration with the very same problem, though in the first iteration it prints correctly "string bool".